# How can I test that event handlers are fired in a WinForms MVP application?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, mvp

I'm creating a WinForms application using the MVP Passive View pattern. My Views fire events, which are then handled by their respective Presenters. I've attempted to ensure that events are handled in the Presenter with both RhinoMocks and Moq to no avail. I couldn't find a way to force RhinoMocks to ignore the behavior of my Presenter's event handler, nor could I find a way to make Moq actually call the event handler.

Any advice would be appreciated. For reference, here's a simplified version of my code. I'd like to be able to verify that, upon FileCellClicked being fired, that FileCellClickedAsync() in FilesTabPresenter is called.

~EDIT~ I've also included a basic idea of what I'd like the test to do. Unfortunately, I get an Exception from Moq saying that invocation is never performed.

Presenter:

```
public class FilesTabPresenter {
        private readonly IFilesTabView mainView;       

        public FilesTabPresenter(IFilesTabView inView) {
            mainView = inView;
            mainView.FileCellClicked += FileCellClickedAsync;
        }

        public virtual async void FileCellClickedAsync(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    //...logic...
}
```

View:

```
public partial class FilesTab : UserControl, IFilesTabView {

    public event GridViewCellEventHandler FileCellClicked;

    public FilesTab() {
            InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void radGridViewFiles_CellClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e) {
            OnFileCellClicked(sender, e);
    }

   private void OnFileCellClicked(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs args) {
        var eventHandler = this.FileCellClicked;
        if (eventHandler != null) {
            eventHandler.Invoke(sender, args);
        }
    }
```

View Interface:

```
public interface IFilesTabView {
    event GridViewCellEventHandler FileCellClicked;
}
```

(Nonfunctional) Test Code:

```
public void VerifyFileCellClickedEventHandled() {                          
    var viewMock = new Mock<IFilesTabView>();                                  
    var presenterStub = new Mock<FilesTabPresenter>(viewMock.Object);
    viewMock.Raise(v => v.FileCellClicked += null, It.IsAny<EventArgs>(),  new GridViewCellEventArgs(null, null, null));
    presenterStub.Verify(x => x.FileCellClickedAsync(It.IsAny<EventArgs>(), It.IsAny<GridViewCellEventArgs>()), Times.AtLeastOnce());
```

}

Comment: I don't think you can invoke the eventhandler outside of a class. Maybe call a method of FilesTabPresenter that does the invoke.

Comment: With Moq you should be able to raise an event by calling `Raise(x => x.FileCellClicked += null, EventArgs.Empty);` on your `Mock<IFilesTabView>` instance. But you didn't show any of your code that was actually using Moq...

Comment: I've got the Raise call down. It's the verification of the EventHandler being called in the concrete class I'm not sure how to check for, if is even possible. I'll add some test code to my question as an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.